# How to print the matching value of key from (Google Guava) Multimap?

Tags: java, collections, key, guava, multimap

I would like to print the matching value of key from multimap. So far I have been unsuccessful at it.

These are the line of code I got so far about it :

````
 dictionaryGG.keys().forEach((key) -> {
            if (userInput.equals(key)) {
                System.out.println("User Input equal to KEY");
                System.out.println("Value associated with matching KEY" + value); // get an error here "value cannot be resolved to a variable"
            }
            System.out.println(key);
        }); ```

(dictionaryGG is my multimap)
````

Comment: Why are you using a multimap?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [Guava Wiki page on `Multimap`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap):

> There are two ways to think of a Multimap conceptually: as a
> collection of mappings from single keys to single values:
>
> ```
> a -> 1
> a -> 2
> a -> 4
> b -> 3
> c -> 5
> ```
>
> or as a mapping from unique keys to collections of values:
>
> ```
> a -> [1, 2, 4]
> b -> [3]
> c -> [5]
> ```

That said, you can fetch values mapped to a multimap key by simply using [`Multimap#get(K)`](https://guava.dev/releases/31.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#get(K)):

```
Collection<String> values = dictionaryGG.get(userInput);
System.out.println("Values: " + values); // assuming you store strings
```

Please note that if you don't expect to have multiple values per key, a simple [`Map` & `Map#get(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) is sufficient.